# How I can delete the System.out.print and to have a unique return

Tags: java, return, system.out

I have a strange problem. I need to collect the different System.out.print and to create a unique String return at the end of program.

How can I do that?

The program following is 'The Caesar's cipher':

```
    public static String cipher(String input2, Integer number) {
    String expression = input2;
    int k = number;
    int lowerBoundlc = 97;
    int upperBoundlc = 122;
    int lowerBounduc = 65;
    int upperBounduc = 90;
    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
        char c = expression.charAt(i);
        int j = (int) c;
        if ((lowerBoundlc <= j && j <= upperBoundlc) || (j == 45)) {
            if (j == 45) {
                System.out.print(Character.toString((char) j));
            } else {
                int addk = j + k;
                if (addk > upperBoundlc) {
                    int lowercase = addk % upperBoundlc;
                    int resultlc = lowerBoundlc + lowercase -1;
                    System.out.print(Character.toString((char) resultlc));
                } else {
                    System.out.print(Character.toString((char) addk));
                }
            }

        } else {
            if ((lowerBounduc <= j && j <= upperBounduc) || (j == 45)) {
                int addnewk = j + k;
                if (addnewk > upperBounduc) {
                    int uppercase = addnewk % upperBounduc;
                    int resultuc = lowerBounduc + uppercase -1;
                    System.out.print(Character.toString((char) resultuc));
                } else {
                    System.out.print(Character.toString((char) addnewk));
                }

            }

        }

    }
    return null;    
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the characters.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: thank you for the suggest. I've done that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by carrying out the following steps:
1. Create an empty `StringBuilder` object at the beginning of the cipher method (this object will hold the sequence of characters that forms the final `String` to be returned by that method).
2. Replace each code line of the form (where x represents an `int` variable)

```
System.out.print(Character.toString((char) x));
```

with the following (where (a) s represents the `StringBuilder` object mentioned in part 1 above, and (b) this resulting line appends the `char` representation of x to s):

```
s.append((char) x);
```

3. Once your `StringBuilder` sequence is complete, obtain the `String` representation of that sequence with the following method (where s is the `StringBuilder` object in question):

```
s.toString();
```

Here's a modified version of the cipher method which utilizes the above approach:

```
public static String cipher(String input2, Integer number) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input2.length());
        int k = number;
        int lowerBoundlc = 97;
        int upperBoundlc = 122;
        int lowerBounduc = 65;
        int upperBounduc = 90;
        for (int i = 0; i < input2.length(); i++) {
            char c = input2.charAt(i);
            int j = (int) c;
            if ((lowerBoundlc <= j && j <= upperBoundlc) || (j == 45)) {
                if (j == 45) {
                    builder.append((char) j);
                } else {
                    int addk = j + k;
                    if (addk > upperBoundlc) {
                        int lowercase = addk % upperBoundlc;
                        int resultlc = lowerBoundlc + lowercase -1;
                        builder.append((char) resultlc);
                    } else {
                        builder.append((char) addk);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                if ((lowerBounduc <= j && j <= upperBounduc) || (j == 45)) {
                    int addnewk = j + k;
                    if (addnewk > upperBounduc) {
                        int uppercase = addnewk % upperBounduc;
                        int resultuc = lowerBounduc + uppercase -1;
                        builder.append((char) resultuc);
                    } else {
                        builder.append((char) addnewk);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of strictly printing the Character.toString((char) *variable*) you can append these strings together using += or alternatively the StringBuilder class.

An example of this would be

```
String s = Character.toString((char) j);
System.out.print(s);

String p = Character.toString((char) resultC);
s += p;
System.out.print(p);
```

After concatenating all the strings together you could return the string s at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String cipher(String input2, Integer number) {

    String expression = input2;
    int k = number;
    int lowerBoundlc = 97;
    int upperBoundlc = 122;
    int lowerBounduc = 65;
    int upperBounduc = 90;

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++) {
        char c = expression.charAt(i);
        int j = (int) c;

        if ((lowerBoundlc <= j && j <= upperBoundlc) || (j == 45)) {
            if (j == 45) {
                StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder(Character.toString((char) j));
                result.append(line);
            } else {
                int addk = j + k;
                if (addk > upperBoundlc) {
                    int lowercase = addk % upperBoundlc;
                    int resultlc = lowerBoundlc + lowercase - 1;
                    StringBuilder appendresultlc = new StringBuilder(Character.toString((char) resultlc));
                    result.append(appendresultlc);
                } else {
                    StringBuilder appendaddk = new StringBuilder(Character.toString((char) addk));
                    result.append(appendaddk);
                }
            }

        } else {
            if ((lowerBounduc <= j && j <= upperBounduc) || (j == 45)) {
                int addnewk = j + k;
                if (addnewk > upperBounduc) {
                    int uppercase = addnewk % upperBounduc;
                    int resultuc = lowerBounduc + uppercase - 1;
                    StringBuilder appendresultuc = new StringBuilder(Character.toString((char) resultuc));
                    result.append(appendresultuc);
                } else {
                    StringBuilder appendaddnewk = new StringBuilder(Character.toString((char) addnewk));
                    result.append(appendaddnewk);

                }

            }

        }

    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use System.out.println() to print messages to other sources. To do that we must reassign the standard output by using the System.setOut(PrintStream p); method of System class

Based on your need set the System.setOut();

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);

PrintStream old = System.out;

// use your special stream
System.setOut(ps);

// All System.out.Println will goes to special stream
System.out.println("This will be written to the string!");

System.out.flush();
System.setOut(old);

String content = new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println("Here: " + content);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple solutions for this problem. But you can solve this problem with minimum changes in your code using this solution...

First of all You have to redirect the default output stream then perform your logic then print your output on the default output stream.
Just update your main method with this..

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
    OutputStream os=System.out;
    //Create piped streams
    PipedInputStream pis=new PipedInputStream(2000);
    PipedOutputStream pos=new PipedOutputStream(pis);
    //Change default output stream
    System.setOut(pos);
    //Logic..
    cipher("stack",4);
    //Change default output stream to console
    System.setOut(os);
    //Read output from PipedOutput Stream & print on console
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String ct=sc.next();
    System.out.print(ct);
}
```

Now whatever you print on standard output stream in method cipher is not printed directly on console.

Even you can write the output of your program in file without any change in method `cipher`.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply append answers to the string using concatenation ('+' operator) & use that string.
you can use String Builder to improve the performance.